# How to use Cordova Camera plugin with File Transfer?

Tags: c#, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, file-transfer

**I am trying to upload a photo taken from the camera, but running into issues with tying the resulting photo with file transfer.**

I have installed the following plugins: 
cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-file, cordova-plugin-file-transfer

I am able to take a picture and display it in an ionic page.  What I don't understand is how to tie that photo with the file-transfer process.  A real end-to-end example of a live photo taken and uploaded.

So far I have come across many examples of taking a photo -- or -- uploading a previously existing file.  But not both in one go.

*On a related note that I have this working using the browser camera functions and can successfully upload the file object into my web service (written in C#).  It works in iOS but recently the Android device no longer offers a live photo to be taken for some reason (would love to know why).*

**Are there any end-to-end examples of taking a photo, uploading it -- and -- into a C# written web-service?**

Comment: ALTERNATIVELY, I have a working web service that correctly receives an image file using the browser's camera capture and input type file.  This file comes in as an object -- how can I get the same kind of file object from Cordova?

Comment: ALTERNATIVELY 2:  I might have to modify my web service to convert the Base64String image data into an array of bytes.  Something like C# code:
   byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(the-bytes-received-from-cordova);

Comment: SOLVED!   I had two issues.  One was that I was confusing the parameters for destinationType / sourceType (see radyz solution below).  The other is that my web service needed to be updated to convert the uploaded stream from Base64String (as I alluded to above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing it like this:

```
var options = {
    quality: 75,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 720,
    targetHeight: 1280,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
};

return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(upload);

function upload(filePath) {
    return $cordovaFileTransfer.upload('http://example.com', filePath, {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'example.jpeg',
        mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
    });
}
```

Comment: I need to take the picture, rather than choose an existing one (which is a different destination type to DATA_URL if I'm not mistaken).  I am able to take the picture and display it, but not sure what to send for the file transfer.

I am trying a different approach now which is to use my existing file transfer web service which works when I send it a file object (as obtained from a browser input type file, with camera capture).  But the Cordova returned file object seems different...

Comment: You can notice that I'm using `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL` which will return the file path where the image is being stored. You can then set this path to an img.src tag (if needed to show a quick preview) or you can pass it to the $cordovaFileTransfer.upload method as shown in the snippet of code above.

This will take a new picture btw, not pick an existing one. The $cordovaCamera.getPicture method will open the camera app in your device.

Comment: You are right;  put it down to tired eyes, but I was changing the source type instead of the destination type.  No wonder nothing was making sense.  Let me see where I go with this now.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Mark it as accepted if it was of any help to you :)

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed part of my problem!  The other part was that I needed to update my web service to convert the uploaded bytes from base64string:  
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(the-bytes-received-from-cordova)